# How does homeomorphism between affine varieties imply isomorphism between coordinate rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible affine varieties, and 
$$F : X\rightarrow Y$$ 
is a morphism of affine varieties which is a **homeomorphism** in the Zariski topology. My question is, how to show 
$$F^\#:A(Y)\rightarrow A(X)
$$
is an isomorphism between those two coordinate rings?

I see that if $F$ is an isomorphism between varieties, the conclusion is obvious. But now $F$ is only a topological homeomorphism.

I think the injective part is easy, because $F$ is homeomorphism, $F(X)$ is dense, thus $F^\#$ is injective by a proven proposition.

Now I have trouble in the surjective case. There is hint in my note, saying that

> Let $g\in A(X)$, we show that for all $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $F(x)$ and a regular function $(V_x, h_x)\in\mathcal{O}_{Y,F(X)}$ such that $F^\#(V_x,h_x)=(F^{-1}(V_x), g\left.\right|_{F^{-1}(V_x)})$.

Could anyone show me how to construct such $h_x$?

---

Update

Sorry I missed an important condition. Following is the original text from the note I am reading. It is an exercise.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible affine varieties. Suppose that $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of affine varieties which is a homeomorphism in the Zariski topology, **which induces isomorphisms $F_x^\#:\mathcal{O}_{Y,F(x)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for every $x\in X$.**

I believe the last statement is of importance, and I think by this, the original question I posted is obvious. We can just let $h_x$ to be the inverse of $g$ under $F_x^\#$.

However, then I need to show $h_x=h_{x'}$ in $V_x\cap V_{x'}$. I can't see how to do it. Could anyone help me?

---

Update

I think I figured it out. For two points $x$ and $x'$, we construct
$$
h_x:=(F_x^\#)^{-1}g
$$

and
$$
h_{x'}:=(F_{x'}^\#)^{-1}g
$$

On the overlapped area $V_x\cap V_{x'}$, since $F$ is a homeomorphism, we have
$$
h_x(y)=h_x\circ F\circ F^{-1}(y) = g\circ F^{-1}(y)
$$

and the same for $h_{x'}$.

Am I right?

Comment: The title and body question don't quite match. It is badly false that if two affine varieties are homeomorphic in the Zariski topology then they are isomorphic as varieties, e.g. all irreducible curves are homeomorphic.

Comment: I don't think this is true: Take $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, $Y=V(x^3-y^2)$ and a map $f:t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$. Then this is a homeomorphism of $X$ and $Y$, but the image of the induced map of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras is $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: @PavelC, sorry I missed a constraint. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, sorry I missed a constraint. Please see my updated post.